# applicationDidEnterBackground, playSoundFileNamed Crash

Tags: ios, crash, playsound, home-button

When I tap Home Button the app calls `AppDelegate` function `applicationDidEnterBackground`, and `applicationWillEnterForeground` after I get back to it.

I use the following code:

```
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

         mainScene.view?.paused = true
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

        mainScene.view?.paused = false
    }
```

and it works fine. I'm able to pause the app and resume it when needed. But if I tap Home Button at the moment when there is a sound (like "gun Fire", or "Coin fall Down" etc.) currently playing in my app with `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed` and then try to resume the app, it crashes. The only way I can resume it normally it is if there aren't any active sounds when I tap Home Button.

Any workaround?

Comment: whats the `error` report info in your `console`?

Comment: thread 1 exc_bad_access (code=1 )

Comment: and the console log?

Comment: @aircraft, console doesn't show anything except - (lldb).

Comment: i've just tried to test it on different iPhone with same IOS 10.1, and here it doesn't crash, but sound that supposed to play when I tapped Home Button doesn't play and console gives me an Error: "SKAction: Error playing sound resource". I guess that is what causing the crash on a different iPhone, but how to work around?

Comment: your question is hard to describe the issue,if it is convenient, you can send your prject to my e-mail:liaodalin19903@126.com